# How to update dll in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I update my `freetextbox`  version into `3.3.0.22838`. I don't know how to update it. i just copy paste my new version in bin.

And I get this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'FreeTextBox, Version=3.1.5.21298, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5962a4e684a48b87' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Line 1:  <%@ page language="C#" masterpagefile="~/Template/BackendTemplate.master" autoeventwireup="true" validaterequest="false" inherits="Backend_Modules_BookManagement, App_Web_wplihlju" title="Untitled Page" %>

Much thanks!

Comment: whats free textbox? some free OSS control or something?

Comment: @giddy, rich textbox in asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check your solution's reference to the assembly.  Right-click > Properties > Specific Version should be set to False.  That or drop the reference to the old one and add a reference to the new one.  Either way you'll need to recompile.  The first suggestion will solve it for all future versions however.

Answer (score 0):

hallo it says on error  that you used different version of control on build you should put version Version=3.1.5.21298 instead of  version 3.3.0.22838...
or you should build your project with version 3.3.0.22838 and deploy all your project....

Answer (score 0):

As you see in the error message FreeTextBox has a public key token and also a version number. when you add a dll as a reference to your application, it binds your application to this publick token key and version number.

so you need to remove your FreeTextBox dll from your application references and add reference to new version to correct your problem.

just open your solution, go to references of your application, remove the FreeTextBox  reference. then right click on references and select **add reference** and then select your new FreeTextBox dll. after rebuild, every thing will go fine.

Comment: @farzin, I already published it. how would i change the version in current system? tnx

Comment: You have your solution. just do as I told in the answer. then upload just your web application dll (asp.net dll - last layer) to your bin directory.
you need to replace your FreeTextBox and all other dll(s) that use FreeTextBox dll. but after updating references in solution and rebuild.

Comment: i already did it. during my local there is no problem but during the deployment in site i received that error.

Comment: It maybe because of asp.net temporary files. do you have access to your server (RDP)?

Comment: i have an access in ftp using filezilla. i just paste the latest dll in ftp and then i received that error.

Comment: you have just one way to correct this.
 - Rebuild your solution using new dll.
 - remove all of your files in bin directory of server
 - browse your default page to cause application pool to restart
 - upload all of files in your local bin directory to server bin directory

if you can, you should ask your hosting to clear asp.net temporary files for your website 

temporary files path :
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[.net version]\Temporary ASP.NET Files\[website name]

Answer (score 0):

The loader cannot find the assembly that was referenced; see that you put your assembly in the application folder or GAC it.

Comment: FreeTextBox dll does not need to be registered in GAC. it is just a simple reference.