# Reference dll cannot be updated in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2015

I have a website and need to update the  dll such as Crystal Report in VS2015. However I added the update dll and rebuild it. There is an error

> Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=12.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The new dll files are version 13. It looks like the website still references the old dll. I searched the solution and found someone has this kind of question [How to update dll in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534973/how-to-update-dll-in-asp-net). However I didn't have the view as it mention

(Double check your solution's reference to the assembly. Right-click > Properties > Specific Version should be set to False)

Would someone tell me how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove and add again the reference to the proper dll

Comment: The crystal report dll is not in the reference list. I re added it but it is same an error. By the way I have another dll and it has same problem. I removed the reference and add it. But it is still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have crystal report dll in your local machine?

Comment: Yes. I had another web project and can be updated the new dll. Only this website had problem.